# Is it possible to browse the source of OpenJDK online?

Tags: mercurial, java

Is it possible to browse the source code of OpenJDK online, just like I can do with SourceForge's projects? I never used Mercury before, so I felt confused.

(Note: I don't want to download the source. I just want to browse it online, to see how some methods are implemented.)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

OpenJDK is now on GitHub: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk

It is a large project, but you will find the implementations of the core classes under [jdk/src/java.base/share/classes](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes).

For instance you can find [the implementation of `java.util.List` here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/List.java).

---

If you need to browse older versions, you still need to use the [old Mercurial interface](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/).

The Mercurial interface there is quite confusing if you are not used to it, and since this is a large project, it can be hard to find what you are looking for.

Here is an example:

To find the JDK6 implementation `java.util.List`, select `jdk6`, `jdk`, select browse. Then browse to `src/share/classes/java/util/List.java`.

You should end up at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/List.java

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went there trying to find the source for java.nio.file.FileRef, but I couldn't find it. Could you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: You can find that one here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/nio/nio/jdk/file/d5e2831c01c4/src/share/classes/java/nio/file/FileRef.java (or perhaps see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410705/best-way-to-determine-if-two-path-reference-to-same-file-in-c#410794 )

Comment: For anyone trying this the default branch number changes. So the procedure described is correct, just don't be surprised if the link doesn't work.

Comment: if you want the JDK7 version, it's here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/nio/file/FileRef.java

Comment: @Patrick: if you replace the changeset ID with 'tip', it will always work. The version it points to may change over time, but it will always be the most up-to-date (in some sense). I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: What does "gate" in the repo name mean?

Comment: @finnw: Very good question. I have no idea: consider asking a top-level question about it.

Comment: Now if I want to see the native code that implements the native methods, where can I find them?

Comment: @Ustaman Sangat: Look under src/windows/native, src/linux/native or src/solaris/native. For instance http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/windows/native/com/sun/security/auth/module/nt.c

Comment: @RasmusFaber Thanks. Now a dumber question, I was looking for Object.hashcode() implementation, can't figure it out from any files at http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/6b46f3c7c97c/src/windows/native/java/lang/

Comment: @Ustaman Sangat: Ah, sorry. Non-platform-specific methods are in src/share/native. java.lang.Object is in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/native/java/lang/Object.c . You will notice that it delegates hashCode() to JVM_IHashCode() which is in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp . This again calls FastHashCode() in http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp , which will end up calling get_next_hash() in the same file.

Comment: But if need to clone the jdk7 latest repo, what is the url?

Comment: FYI, the Java 8 version of that example [`List`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/List.java) class source file.

Answer (score 9):

The latest **JDK 8** OpenJDK *Java Class Library* source code can be found here: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to browse the repositories and look at just the bits you want.
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/
Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Not exactly. I went there before I asked but I couldn't find my way around the Mercurial interface. :(

Comment: Sorry, I actually went to http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio and tried to find my way from there. I'll check this link again. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the basic step to get **latest** or **any released version** of `Openjdk 8` (or any existing java version) source code, and use them in `Eclipse`.

**Steps**:

- ***[browse source]***
- Open url for jdk, e.g http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/
- click `tags`
- choose proper tag, e.g `jdk8u73-b02`
- then click `browse`,
- then browse into folder `src/share/classes`,
- ***[download source]***
- then click one of `bz2` / `zip` / `gz`, to download source in relevant compressed format, (*e.g for `jdk8u73-b02` in `zip` format, the url will be: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/archive/2ab13901d6f1.zip/src/share/classes/*)
- ***[use in eclipse]***
- uncompress it,
- zip the folder "classes/", make "classes/" as the root dir of .zip file, (e.g first `cd jdk-2ab13901d6f1/src/share/`, then `zip -r openjdk_8u73_b2_src.zip classes/`)
- move the created zip file to proper location, it will stay there for a while, (e.g `mv openjdk_8u73_b2_src.zip /media/Eric/software/java/jdk/openjdk/openjdk8u73-b02/source/`)
- in eclipse, specify source file for jars of installed jre, could specify the source attachment for each jar of installed jre respectively, the most common jar is probably `rt.jar`,
- optionally, might need refresh project to make it totally take effect, not sure is that necessary,
- test it: in eclipse, `ctrl + shift + t`, then input `Cancellable`, select the `sun.nio.fs.Cancellable` of corresponding installed jre,
  if the source code is available, then it's good, because this source is not available in `jdk_home/src.zip`, it must be from the additional openjdk source,
- switch source back: could switch back to use "jdk_home/src.zip", if don't want to use the external openjdk source,
- ok

Answer (score 6):

Append a "/file" to the root URLs to view the browser like  this:

- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/
- http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file

Answer (score 2):

**Grepcode.com** is great for similar things - not only OpenJDK sources, with searching in classes/methods and links between classes directly in highlighted code:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/net/Socket.java

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answers, the source code repository is at https://hg.openjdk.java.net

However, the OpenJDK team mirrors some of the projects on GitHub: https://github.com/openjdk

Including the latest Java version project (https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk): https://github.com/openjdk/jdk

Answer (score 1):

Surely http://hg.openjdk.java.net is one good option. The other equally good source is [zGrepCode](https://zgrepcode.com/) https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/ . It has both Open JDK and Oracle java versions.

Comment: zgrepcode looks like a click baiter. Lots of popups and ads showed up.