# Collision resolution in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

When we put key-value pair in HashMap this could happen the hashcode of two keys could be same then how in this condition storing and retrieval of key-value will be handled.

**Update**

What I understand so far is that if two object key has same hash code then both key objects will be stored in same bucket and when I will say `get(key)` then out of two objects with matching hashcode which element to fetch is decided by `object.equals()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980757/how-do-hashtables-deal-with-collisions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945894/java-hashmap-confusion-about-collision-handling-and-the-get-method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to retrieve some object from hashmap and there exists several objects with the same hashcode, java will call `equals()` to determine the right object.

That is why it is so important to override `equals()` when overriding `hashCode()`.

Comment: thanks for simple and clear answer but I still have confusion so can you please comment on update of my question

Comment: Yes, that's right. We will iterate over the list of keys in the bucket and call `equals()` on our key comparing it with each of them until we find a match.

Answer (score 3):

Each bucket is represented by a linked list, so there is no limit, other than heap space, on the number of entries in a bucket. There are fewer buckets than possible hashCode results, so multiple hash codes are mapped to the same bucket, not just keys with the same hashCode.

A `hashCode()` with many collisions, or a HashMap with too few buckets, can make some linked lists long. Good performance depends on short linked lists, because the final stage in a look up is a linear scan of one of the linked lists.

I agree with the previous answer that a match depends on both `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: +1 for "There are fewer buckets than possible hashCode results, so multiple hash codes are mapped to the same bucket, not just keys with the same hashCode"