# How hashcode create in internally?

Tags: java, object, hashcode

Anyone tell me how java create hashcode internally ?

```
package swain.javainterviewhub.blogspot.in;


    public class JavaInterviewHub {

        public static  void main(String[] args) {

           String str="Alex";
           System.out.println(str.hashCode());
        }

    }
    Output:2043454
```

Key Hashcode Algorithm Hashcode

Alex A(1) + L(12) + E(5) + X(24)=42

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an object's hash code if hashCode() is not overridden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237720/what-is-an-objects-hash-code-if-hashcode-is-not-overridden)

Comment: For a more challenging problem, try generating haiku (5 syllable, 7 syllable, 5 syllables) as a String which has a hashCode() of 0. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29):

> The hash code for a String object is computed as
>
> ```
>  s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```

You can also look at the source for additional information (Oracle JDK 8u45 here).

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

       for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: That's a simple logic. Bang on my head :D

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ that javadoc hurt my eyes for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

Hash code generation in Java depends on the type of the object in question. For Strings, the algorithm is described in the Java docs ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)).

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as

```
 s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)