# What happening in Object.hashCode() method?

Tags: java, hashcode

As far as I know `Object.hashCode()` method has `native` implementation. I particularly interested in: is there any randomization in this method? 
I have class straight forward derived from the Object.class without redefined `hashCode` method. Correct me if I am wrong but when we call `==` operator we compare references of such objects, alias compare hashcodes. 
So do we always get `false`

```
//pseudocode
new SomeObject(3) == new SomeObject(3)
```

because of randomization involved into `Object.hashCode()` method?

Comment: "when we call == operator we compare references of such objects" - yes, so hashCode isn't involved at all. It's not clear why you think it would be.

Comment: @Rudik, Don't confuse `equals()` with `==`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237720/what-is-an-objects-hash-code-if-hashcode-is-not-overridden/32454673#32454673 Take a look an answer of @TagirValeev

Comment: @JonSkeet At the page of 613 Bruce Eckel 'Thinking in java 4th edition' is written: `the default implementation of hashCode( ) does use the object address` So was I partially right about randomization as far as address setting process is more or less random?

Comment: Thanks, @SergeyMorozov, it answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know Object.hashCode() class is native.

Correct.

> I particularly interested in: is there any randomization in this method?

The hashcode returned by `Object.hashCose()` IS *typically* based on a machine address of the object *at some time during its lifetime*.  The address, and hence the hashcode may be influenced by a variety of random factors, depending on the application.

However, this does not mean that the hashcodes are random.  In fact, if you allocated two objects one after the other and immediately got their hashcodes, it is **likely** that there will be a strong correlation between the two hashcodes.

Likely ... but not guaranteed.

> Correct me if I am wrong but when we call == operator we compare references of such objects.

Correct.

> ... alias compare hashcodes.

If you are saying that `==` involves hashcodes, that is INCORRECT.  `==` is implemented by comparing the current machine addresses of the objects.

> So do we always get false because of randomization involved into Object.hashCode() method?

No.   In your example, you get `false` because the object references are different!

In fact, it is possible for two distinct `Object` instances to have the same hashcode.

```
  o1 == o2 IMPLIES o1.hashcode() == o2.hashcode()    is TRUE

  o1.hashcode() == o2.hashcode() IMPLIES o1 == o2    is FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

The Object hascode is just a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()), not a pointer. So the `==` will compare the references not the hashcode.

The general contract of hashCode from [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) is :

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>     execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>     consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>     of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the
>     equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
>     two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required
>     that if two objects are unequal according to the
>     equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>     each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hash tables.

The keyword `native` tells the the implementation is done at native code using JNI(Java Native Interface).

Also if you are overriding the `hashcode` method dont forget that your implementation should satisfy the above contract else you may get wrong output, where it is used. Say `HashMap` class.

More info: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)