# Why java insist developers to add a comparison mechanism rather than using a default comparison mechanism while working on sorted collection?

Tags: java, comparison, default

Say we have a class `Foo` like

```
class Foo {
    private int attr1;
    private String attr2;
    // getters and setters.
    // hashCode and equals not overrided.
}
```

So while adding references of `Foo` to a Set or a Map (as a key) duplicates will be identified based on their address locations. Now if I override `hashCode` and `equals` based on `attr2`, duplicates will be identified based on the `value` of `attr2`. That's how duplicate filtration works in Java - Look for any user defined mechanism, if present use that otherwise use the default mechanism.

If we try to add references of `Foo` to a sorted collection like `TreeSet`, `TreeMap` it will throw `ClassCastException` saying that there is no comparison mechanism. So we can make it either `Comparable` or `Comparator` type and can define a comparison mechanism.

So my question is while finding duplicates, if the user hasn't defined any mechanism Java will look for default mechanism, but while sorting or comparing it insists user to define a mechanism. Why won't it go for a default mechanism, for example comparing references based on their `hashcode`? Is it because any OOPs concept or any concept in Java may be violated if they go for a default comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **TL;DR** Give me a sensible way of defining a total ordering between opaque objects.

It is sensible to say, lacking any other information, that objects are the same only if they are physically the same. This is what the default `equals` and `hashCode` do.

It is not sensible, and indeed makes no sense, to say that one object is "bigger" than another because a digest of its memory location is bigger.

Even more dammingly for your proposed mechanism, in modern Java the old adage that a `hashCode` is a memory location is [actually incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32454673/2071828). An `Object` is assigned a random number at construction and that is used as the `hashCode`.

So you are really proposing:

"*Lacking any information about the objects to be ordered, we will order them completely at random*"

I cannot think of any situation where this default behaviour is:

1. expected
2. useful

Comment: good1 that helped in changing my concept about hashcode. But using hashcode for comparison was just an example. I was wondering why comparison can't be done on any other way rather than throwing an exception

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran suggest "another way" that makes sense. I propose that there is none.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran look at a class which does implement `Comparable`, e.g. `String`: if you didn't know anything about `String`, how would you know that you need to [compare only the `char[] value` field](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java#1141), as opposed to any other field it defines?