# javaws system property to relax or remove security?

Tags: java, security, java-web-start

Having upgraded to Java 7 (Oracle/Sun JDK, not OpenJDK), if I try to test my app under Web Start with `javaws`, it tells me "Application Blocked by Security Settings".  I can use the Java control panel to reduce security from high to medium to get it to work (it asks me if I want to launch an unsigned app), but that also reduces the security level for my web browser.  Is there any system property that'll let me do `javaws -J-Dkey=value` to get that one instance of javaws to relax or ignore security with regards to what will launch (but otherwise keep security the same)?

**EDIT**: If anyone could point me to where the Java 7 source code for `javaws` is, I'd be happy to read through the code to find the answer.

**EDIT 2**: When I set Java security to medium through the Java control panel, launching my app with `javaws` results in it asking me if I want to run an unsigned app; this is what I want to duplicate.  The control panel sets security to medium via adding the system property `deployment.security.level=MEDIUM` to the file `~/.java/deployment/deployment.properties`.  I've tried two ways to use this:

1) Pass `-J-Ddeployment.security.level=MEDIUM` to `javaws`.  This results in my app fully launching without it asking me if I want to run an unsigned app.

2) Pass `-J-Ddeployment.system.config=~/.java/deployment/FOO.properties`, where `FOO.properties` is a copy of the normal `deployment.properties` file, with `deployment.security.level=MEDIUM` added manually.  Again, this results in my app fully launching without it asking me if I want to run an unsigned app.

**EDIT 3**: Note that I'm using Oracle/Sun JDK, not OpenJDK.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827002/browse-jdk-7-source-files-on-the-web)

Answer (score 1):

- Have you tried creating your own custom `SecurityManager`?
- Have you tried using `java.security.AllPermission` (just to test if this is a fix for you) ?

Related specs:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html
- http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html
- http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc.html

This may be very relevant to you:

- http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip20.html

EDIT: Re: javaws, check out the invocation of javaws itself. I did `cat /usr/bin/javaws` and here we go:

```
#!/bin/bash

JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
LAUNCHER_BOOTCLASSPATH="-Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/icedtea-web/netx.jar"
LAUNCHER_FLAGS=-Xms8m
CLASSNAME=net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.Boot
BINARY_LOCATION=/usr/bin/javaws
PROGRAM_NAME=javaws
CP=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar

JAVA_ARGS=( )
ARGS=( )
COMMAND=()

i=0
j=0

while [ "$#" -gt "0" ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -J*)
      JAVA_ARGS[$i]="${1##-J}"
      i=$((i+1))
      ;;
    *)
      ARGS[$j]="$1"
      j=$((j+1))
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done

k=0
COMMAND[k]="${JAVA}"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="${LAUNCHER_BOOTCLASSPATH}"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="${LAUNCHER_FLAGS}"
k=$((k+1))
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt "${#JAVA_ARGS[@]}" ]; do
  COMMAND[k]="${JAVA_ARGS[$i]}"
  i=$((i+1))
  k=$((k+1))
done
COMMAND[k]="-classpath"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="${CP}"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="-Dicedtea-web.bin.name=${PROGRAM_NAME}"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="-Dicedtea-web.bin.location=${BINARY_LOCATION}"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="-Djava.security.manager"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="-Djava.security.policy=/etc/icedtea-web/javaws.policy"
k=$((k+1))
COMMAND[k]="${CLASSNAME}"
k=$((k+1))
j=0
while [ "$j" -lt "${#ARGS[@]}" ]; do
  COMMAND[k]="${ARGS[$j]}"
  j=$((j+1))
  k=$((k+1))
done

"${COMMAND[@]}"

exit $?
```

#### The most important is that a `javaws.policy` is loaded.

Comment: I want for the security to be like normal for a Web Start app *except* that the app is allowed to actually launch. I've edited my question to make that clear.

Comment: I'm using Oracle/Sun JDK, not OpenJDK; it's javaws is a binary executable.  I tried making sure that java.security.policy=/usr/java/default/jre/lib/security/javaws.policy, but that didn't help.

Comment: Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start). 

"by default they run in the same sandbox as applets, with several minor extensions like allowing to load and save the file that is explicitly selected by the user through the file selection dialog. **Only signed applications can be configured to have additional or even all permissions.**" Have you tried to add a signature?

Comment: And this might come handy, too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: And this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/security.html