# How is the java.util.priorityqueue implemented?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, queue, priority-queue

Does anyone know the implementation details for the standard java priority queue?  heap?  skiplist?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683041/java-how-do-i-use-a-priorityqueue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javadoc says it's a heap: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

First sentence, first paragraph:

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap.

Comment: I was confused with priority heap a bit. if u look at the source code, it uses heapify method so balance the heap. so yeah it s the heap structure. it would be interesting to see a skiplist implementation.

Comment: Thanks.  Clearly I skipped the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Source Luke:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java

Alse see this awesomely helpful answer explaining how to use the horrible web front end for Mercurial:
[Is it possible to browse the source of OpenJDK online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410756/is-it-possible-to-browse-the-source-of-openjdk-online)