# Hash Map Internals exhaustive details

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I am looking for internals of hash map.Some exhaustive detailed info about buckets, Node inside it,  Map.Entry etc.

I cant find any online stuff which has exhaustive details about this. I tried going thru source of HashMap inside rt.jar but its too complex to handle.

Please suggest where will i be able to find in detail internal working of hash map.

Thanks

Comment: The source code for [HashMap can be found at GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java).

Answer (score 1):

to the best of my knowledge, rt.jar does not contain sources.
However, OpenJDK is, well, an open source JDK implementation.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410756/is-it-possible-to-browse-the-source-of-openjdk-online) has the info on browsing its source code

This is the direct link to the class you were asking: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java
The internal documentation is quite extensive.

Comment: Thanks for providing the info but i am finding the source code quite hard to understand the internals and data structures internally. Is there any doc available which provides the overview of hash map internals like bucket creation, modification, extension etc. Something which gives detailed insight into hash map, then i can go for full code understanding which will be easier to comprehend then

Comment: Like I said, the source code contains an extensive documentation regarding implementation.  Did you try to read it?

Comment: starting at line #143

Answer (score 0):

Download JDK (not JRE) and look for a *src.zip* file at the root of the installation path. All source code is there.