# Algorithm for Linked list implementation in java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, implementation

Does Java implement w-linkedlist as the implementation of java.util.LinkedList? If not, which algorithm is implemented?

Edit: Please read doubly-linkedlist (generally 'w' character is used casually for doubly)

Comment: What is a w-linkedlist ?

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Where can I see the Sun Java source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261015/where-can-i-see-the-sun-java-source-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a starting point:

[java.util.LinkedList](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/util/LinkedList.java.html)

Comment: Yeah, it's open source for a while now. Just look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, then the answer will be *Yes*, because the `LinkedList.Node` class contains links to the previous and the next elements:

```
Node<E> next;
Node<E> prev;
```