# repository with java's source code

Tags: java, open-source

Are there any repository (git, svn, csv etc.) with java's source code? I know there is zip archive in jdk distribution but I would prefer single repository as history is trackable and it is easy to switch to any point of time in the history.

Comment: @mre He's talking about a git repo with the Java source on it. Like on GitHub or something. I don't know of any, infact I don't know if Oracle allows it.

Comment: I am asking about online repository with java source code.

Comment: This question has useful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/261015/422353

Comment: You mean Java_'s_ source code?

Comment: @entonio, yep, I mean java source code

Comment: @michaelnesterenko, "java source code" means any source code that happens to be written in java. You apparently mean "Java's source code" (notice the apostrophe), which means the source code of the Java runtime.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko we're pleased to help :) As far as I know, there is no public repository, Sun only released the source as part of its distributions but if I'm not mistaken anyone could apply to get repository access; but I would be surprised if Oracle kept that policy (if it was ever like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) as well as [Lambda](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda) with Mercurial.

For both you have to download and then make it before its usable, which may or may not be what you're after.

If you're after the "official" Oracle supplied JDK then the only way I know to get hold of that is via the sanctioned download from Oracle itself (or included with most JDK downloads too)