# How to deeply review internal Java implementation of certain function?

Tags: java, random

I use Java 8.0 (IDE Eclipse). And sometimes want to drill-down into specific implementation (fields, methods) of which original developers (of language internals itself) have chosen. 
In many times Wikipedia is too general (helps, but not enough), while other sources answer to just-near, but not exact my question. 
And besides it - I am sometimes curious to see by myself (for both "want to be more independent" and "seeing by myself eyes is best to understand and be convinced" reasons).

How can I see inside, like this ?

My specific questions for now (as example and I ask to really know how-to):
How internally random numbers generated in Java, I mean what the exact algorithm for output Java uses (using Math.random()) ?

Comment: The sources come with the JDK (src.zip). Look at them.

Comment: See the answers to [Where can I see the Sun Java source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/261015/44522).

Comment: It seems The Math.random is kind of complex. If you don't find any detailed information on stackoverflow or google, you can type Math.random() in a Java application in eclipse, click on the "random()" and press the F3 button to see what code gets called. Keep pressing F3 to keep going down the rabbit hole. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like [this implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/Math.java#Math.random%28%29), but keep in mind that it is not guaranteed to be implemented the same way across different implementations.  Ideally, as a user of an API, you should not need to know how it is implemented; the implementation may change in future versions, as long as the API stays the same.

Comment: *In general, as a user of an API, you should not need to know how it is implemented* you may want to check this if you spot this is your bottleneck or for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

simply clicking on `methods` and `classes` of your choice while holding down `CTRL` reveals the sourcecode. As long as you installed the JDK you will see even the most basic implementations - without exception. If you cant open an implementation you will have to install the appropriate sourcecode.

Comment: Be sure to list which program you're speaking of; not everyone uses the same IDE

Comment: the whole question is about eclipse. Maybe you should've read it.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse , you can do this be ctrl+click on the method name or pressing f3. You can also hold shift and hover over the method or class.