# Viewing Implementation details of included algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

How can I see how a specific algorithm in Java is implemented? For example, the Arrays.sort() method sorts different types of arrays. However, I'm unable to understand what goes on under the hood. How do I see how this method is implemented?

Comment: The source codes are contained in src.zip that comes with the JDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I see the Sun Java source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261015/where-can-i-see-the-sun-java-source-code)

Answer (score 1):

You can download java sources from the [official](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) site.

And for non-open java libraries you can use **decompiler**.