# Why extra var2 byte array is used in hashCode method of StringLatin1 utility class?

Tags: java, java-11

Current code is:

```
public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
    int h = 0;
    byte[] var2 = value;
    int var3 = value.length;

    for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var3; ++var4) {
        byte v = var2[var4];
        h = 31 * h + (v & 255);
    }

    return h;
}
```

Possible code is:

```
public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
    int h = 0;
    int var2 = value.length;

    for(int var3 = 0; var3 < var2; ++var3) {
        byte v = value[var3];
        h = 31 * h + (v & 255);
    }

    return h;
}
```

In `java.lang` package, there is a utility class called `StringLatin1`. This class has `hashCode` method which will be called from `String` class's `hashCode` method, if current string value is latin.

PS: I use Java 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever current code you have posted is not the real code; it's the decompiled code which may vary from decompiler to decompiler and therefore you can not rely on it.

Comment: Where I can get a real code. Can you please give link to a open source repository on github?

Comment: Please check http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java. You can also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261015/where-can-i-see-the-source-code-of-the-sun-jdk

Comment: @SeydazimovNurbol OpenJDK projects use Mercurial: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/. Here's `StringLatin1` for JDK 11: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/StringLatin1.java#l193. Also, the JDK typically comes with a `src.zip` file which contains many of the _Java_ source files (but not any of the native source files).

Comment: @slaw how people contributes to Java? Is there a open source repo in github?

Comment: @SeydazimovNurbol Read-only mirror on GitHub: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk. Information I could find about contributing: https://openjdk.java.net/contribute/

Comment: Why don’t you check your JDK folder for the `lib/src.zip` first?

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard pattern of the for-each loop.

When you write

```
for(Type variable: expression) {
    // body
}
```

the `expression` will be evaluated exactly once at the beginning of the loop and the resulting collection or array reference is remembered throughout the loop. This also implies, that if `expression` is a variable and this variable is assigned within the loop body, it has no effect on the ongoing loop.

The [relevant part of the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2-300-B) says:

> …
>
> - Otherwise, the *Expression* necessarily has an array type, `T[]`.
>
>   Let `L1` ... `Lm` be the (possibly empty) sequence of labels immediately preceding the enhanced `for` statement.
>
>   The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to a basic `for` statement of the form:
>
>   ```
>   T[] #a = Expression;
>   L1: L2: ... Lm:
>   for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
>       {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
>       Statement
>   }
>   ```
>
>   `#a` and `#i` are automatically generated identifiers that are distinct from any other identifiers (automatically generated or otherwise) that are in scope at the point where the enhanced `for` statement occurs.
>
>   *TargetType* is the declared type of the local variable in the header of the enhanced `for` statement.

If you compare the decompiled version

```
public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
    int h = 0;
    byte[] var2 = value;
    int var3 = value.length;

    for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var3; ++var4) {
        byte v = var2[var4];
        h = 31 * h + (v & 255);
    }

    return h;
}
```

with [the actual source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/StringLatin1.java#l193)

```
public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
    int h = 0;
    for (byte v : value) {
        h = 31 * h + (v & 0xff);
    }
    return h;
}
```

you will recognize the translation. `var2`, `var3`, and `var4` are all synthetic variables. Things to note:

- In principle, a compiler could analyze the scenario to recognize that `value` is a local variable which is not assigned in the loop body, so no additional variable would be needed here. But the savings compared to following the standard translation strategy have not been considered worth implementing the additional logic.
- Likewise, it’s the compilers decision whether to remember the invariant array size in another local variable. As shown above, the specification does not mandate it.

You could say that it is a weakness of the decompiler not to recognize the for-each loop and translate it back, however, there’s generally an ambiguity when trying to map compiled code to source code constructs, as a lot of variants exist to produce the same code.